# Query writing based on output format

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i need some assistance in writing a query that returns o/p in a specific format.Here are the data values. They need to be grouped based on their 3rd column and 2nd column.I need a query in such a way that for every unique combination of 2nd and 3rd column values the set of 1st column rows need to be output. But when i used group by the rows are missing.

Comment: What table structure do you have? Which **FIELDS**?

Comment: how are the output be formatted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use this:

> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Column1 SEPARATOR '-') AS Column1, Column2, Column3, Column5
>   FROM Table 
>   GROUP BY Column2, Column3, Column5;